# I would like to know how I can make shorter the text box filter by columns in primefaces Datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I would like to know how I can make shorter the text box filter by columns in primefaces Datatable.
my columns look like this:

```
 <p:column style="width:10%" sortBy="#{item.tipoFacturaUtil.esMercantil}" 
    filterBy="#{item.tipoFacturaUtil.esMercantil}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Mercantil"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{(item.tipoFacturaUtil.esMercantil) eq true ? 'Si':'No'}"/>
 </p:column>
```

Comment: If you mean how to style the html generated by primefaces you can use css to do that (apply `with` or something like that)

Comment: If you want to make them all shorter it's straight forward. To customize the size of each of them then it's more tricky.